# Populating several gridviews on click of one button

Tags: database, vb.net, gridview, buttonclick

I am programming in VB.net.  I am trying to populate 2 gridview tables by searching an email address against my database.  When the user clicks on the search button i want my program to take the value from a textbox, search the email address against my database and then display the user profile in either, or both my 'ScrumMaster' table and my 'Developers' table.  I do not know how to get all of this to happen in one 'btnSearchEmail_Click' method.  Currently the code I have is

```
 Protected Sub btnSearchEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchEmail.Click

End Sub


Protected Sub ScrumMastersDataSource_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles ScrumMastersDataSource.Selecting
    Dim db As New AgileClassesDataContext()

    Dim enteredEmail = txtEnteredEmail.Text

    Dim scrumMasters = (From u In db.Users
                      Join ur In db.UserRoles On u.UserId Equals ur.UserId
                      Join r In db.Roles On ur.RoleId Equals r.RoleId
                      Where r.RoleId = 2 And u.Email = enteredEmail
                      Select u).Distinct

    e.Result = scrumMasters
End Sub


Protected Sub DevelopersDataSource_Selecting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles DevelopersDataSource.Selecting
    Dim db As New AgileClassesDataContext()

    Dim enteredEmail = txtEnteredEmail.Text

    Dim developers = (From u In db.Users
                      Join ur In db.UserRoles On u.UserId Equals ur.UserId
                      Join r In db.Roles On ur.RoleId Equals r.RoleId
                      Where r.RoleId = 3 And u.Email = enteredEmail
                      Select u).Distinct

    e.Result = developers
End Sub
```

As you can see there are 3 methods here.  I want to place the 'ScrumMastersDataSource_Selecting' and 'DevelopersDataSource_Selecting' within 'btnSearchEmail_Click' event so that they both run when 'btnSearchEmail' is clicked.  As an email address may be linked to both the developer and scrum master roles, the duplication is not an issue.  Any advice would be welcome.  I hope this question makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (this is a mix of C#/VB.NET) :

```
private void RefreshGrids()
{
    ScrumMastersDataSource.DataSource = GetListScrum(txtEnteredEmail.Text);
    ScrumMastersDataSource.DataBind();
    DevelopersDataSource.DataSource = GetListDev(txtEnteredEmail.Text);
    DevelopersDataSource.DataBind();
}

Protected Sub btnSearchEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchEmail.Click

    RefreshGrids();

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your post to include a single-quote after your class variable comment.